# Change wordpress wp-content/uploads/ paths to load from 2 different hard disk in the same server

Tags: scale

Change wordpress wp-content/uploads/ paths to load from 2 different hard disk in the same server

So basically there only 1 machine with 2 hard drives

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs              16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 16G  586M   16G   4% /run
tmpfs                 16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg-root   98G   92G  592M 100% /
/dev/sda2           1008M  229M  729M  24% /boot
/dev/sdb1            224G  121G  103G  55% /backup
tmpfs                3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

now my dev/mapper is full with images /wp-content/uploads
how i make wordpress save to the other hard drive from now on but still be able to use the old images from old hard drive

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a reliable way you can do this as to access your pictures via the web they need to be within in your websites root director, however you could probably work with symbolic links to the other hard drive but I would not recommend this

Comment: what do you suggest ?

Comment: are your images all optimized for web ? You can use a plugin for this for example Smush ? this can save you some storage space.

Comment: yes it could save some but still need a long term solution like serving the images from some cloud or something